# Powershell does not close using exit in my script

Tags: powershell

Here is my code.  The first two options work but not the third. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am a bit of a newbie to powershell.  Thanks.

```powershell
$opt = Read-Host "Type 1 to login | Type 2 to disconnect | Type 3 to Exit"
write-host $opt

If ($opt -eq '1') {
$user = "myusername"

$UserCredential = Get-Credential -credential $user

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session
}

ElseIf ($opt -eq '2') {
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
} 

ElseIf ($opt -eq '3') {
Exit
}
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Does this code placed in `.ps1` file? In that case `Exit` only exit that `.ps1` file, not PowerShell itself.

Comment: I am trying to have it exit the script as well as close the shell.

Comment: Run the file on the `PowerShell.exe` command line and it will do what you want.  If you run PowerShell and then ran the script from within, it won't close the shell.

Comment: I am confused between running the file on the PowerShell.exe command line and running powershell.  If I run PowerShell is that not a shell with a command line?

Comment: @rhelou, you can ask PowerShell to run specific script file by command line parameters: `PowerShell.exe -File FileName.ps1`. In that case PowerShell will exit, when it finish executing given script file. You also can execute interactive PowerShell session: `PowerShell.exe`. And than run script in it: `.\FileName.ps1`. In that case, when script finish executing, you will return in interactive PowerShell session.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to close the shell then rather than use `exit`, use this instead:

```
$Host.SetShouldExit(0)
```

Thanks to @PetSerAl for point out this option to gracefully shutdown the PowerShell process rather than just kill it with `Stop-Process $pid`.

BTW anybody else that stumbles upon your script might find it rude that you closed their shell.  Perhaps 3 should be simply `exit script` and 4 is `exit and close shell`?

Comment: Is not it will be better to allow PowerShell to exit gracefully? `$Host.SetShouldExit(0)`

Comment: That does have the advantage of allowing you to set the exit code.  Then again, I suspect the OP doesn't care about an exit code.